# Difference Between Magento Community and Enterprise Editions

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I Have worked with Magento Community Edition but never worked in Enterprise Editions.

Before The Start New Project in Enterprise Editions. I Need to Know Major Differences Between Them.

Comment: refer this link http://www.logicsolutions.com/difference-between-magento-community-and-magento-enterprise/

Comment: Thanks Jeeva But There is Only One Image. that is not good for my understanding.

Comment: May be this one helps to you :: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114-home.html?_ga=1.205898451.1744684703.1470292374

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer these links & you will get idea,

http://www.logicsolutions.com/difference-between-magento-community-and-magento-enterprise/

https://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-enterprise-vs-magento-community/

https://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2014/02/26/magento-community-vs-enterprise-which-solution-fits-your-business

https://commercesciences.com/articles/magento-enterprise-vs-magento-community

https://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2014/02/26/magento-community-vs-enterprise-which-solution-fits-your-business

Answer (score 1):

**Features**

In this grid I’m not showing all differences between the two editions of Magento but the ones that typically have a real impact on the decision making process. Please note that anything in Magento Community that say weak means that it’s difficult to use or not robust to be considered worthy of mention. Other items are only featured in Magento Enterprise.
[image]

**Support**

There is a very significant difference between the levels of support for both of these editions. Magento (owned by eBay) staff’s full time support that will help any organization that has purchased a copy of Magento Enterprise. This provides stability to an organization when there is a falling out with the partner or they need emergency assistance. There is no support directly from the software creator on the community version so your ultimate fall back is the community which could take some time to provide any type of targeted response.

[image]

More:
https://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2014/02/26/magento-community-vs-enterprise-which-solution-fits-your-business